# How to prevent other applications from define same permission name

Tags: android, permissions

My application define a permission with android:protectionLevel="signature".

```
<permission android:name="my.app.permission.EXAMPLE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

My intention is make application modules that can be launched only by my signed app. These application modules have android:permission in its activities.
This works fine. but...
A third-party app can use the same permission name and changed the protection level to normal, like this

```
<permission android:name="my.app.permission.EXAMPLE" android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

If my app is installed first, i can prevent others apps to override the permission. However, if one uninstalls my app and then installs his app it redefines the permission.

Is it possible prevent other application use the same permission name, for example, giving the permission a unique id like application package?

Although the Manifest is encrypted, anyone can read the permission name in log cat when it tries to start the activity that requires this permission (An exception is thrown having the required permission name).

Comment: good question, my guess is that you have no way to limit other applications from doing this though.

Comment: This is a security issue. I cannot grant that my signed app modules will be launched only my signed core app, because a unsigned app can replace my permission defining a low level protection and then use my signed modules.

Comment: You could set up a test by creating a modified version of your app with different package name, signature and protectionLevel=normal. See what happens when both apps are on the same device. My guess is, that a) the signature check will kick in first and make sure that the rogue app has no access to your app that requires the correct signature. And b) that identical permission strings with different levels of protectionLevel can co-exist on the same device.

Comment: @Dennix One option you have to add another layer of security is add some sort of encrypted Extra to the intent that you use to start the module activities. And program them in such a way that if this extra is not present and proper to simply close without doing anything. That way if your module activities were started from another source they would not have this extra and the modules would appear to do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

There's no enforcement, only convention. Like the rest of the Java world, it loosely relies on domain name registration infrastructure. The idea is that you prefix your permission name with your public Internet domain name (e. g. `com.myawesomecompany.myapp.MYPERMISSION`) which you own.

Uniqueness of domain names is enforced by the registrar community, naturally.

Yes, the system is open for abuse.

EDIT: if you're securing a broadcast-based channel, you can add a two-way signature check if you feel like it. Call Context.sendBroadcast() with the permission name as a second parameter.

EDIT2: I feel you're overthinking this while closing your eyes at the bigger Android app security picture. Which is not impressive. Abusing the privilege infrastructure is not how one hacks into an Android app. If I set out to intercept your intents, I won't be putting together a fake intent receiver (activity, service). Instead, I'd connect with a debugger to the genuine receiver in your app, signature and all.

With publicly available tools, it takes minutes to put togther an Eclipse project for a given APK. Load it up into Eclipse, connect to a running process, set breakpoints in relevant system APIs (Android is open source, remember), voila. With a bit of extra effort, you can get decompiled Java sources for an APK and debug in terms of YOUR methods, as opposed to system ones.

Comment: even though i use my public internet domain name to prefix my permission, it does not avoid another application to use the same prefix.

I think that Android should tie the permission name with the package name of the application.

Comment: Like I said - it's open for deliberate abuse.

Comment: I think that Android should tie the permission name with the package name of the application. Thus, two different application won´t have same permission definition.

Comment: I've never tried, but chances are the check for permission name collisions is done at package installation time. It's possible to set up an experiment - create a deliberate collision (with different signatures, no less), and try to install both packages on a device. I suspect the second APK will fail.

Comment: I made this test. The second apk install normally, but the permission definition remains from the first apk. The problem is when the first apk is uninstalled and a second apk is installed redefining the permision.

Comment: Would a reverse signature check help? See Context.sendBroadcast(Intent, String). It makes sure the receiver holds the permission as defined by the sender.

Answer (score 2):

copyed from Google Andorid Doc:
Note: The system does not allow multiple packages to declare a permission with the same name, unless all the packages are signed with the same certificate. If a package declares a permission, the system does not permit the user to install other packages with the same permission name, unless those packages are signed with the same certificate as the first package. To avoid naming collisions, we recommend using reverse-domain-style naming for custom permissions, for example com.example.myapp.ENGAGE_HYPERSPACE.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent other applications from changing your permission level, you can use system predefine permissions which have level "signature".  No other regular app can define permission before system.

Use system permission to protect your resource doesn't mean your app have to sign with platform key.

example:

```
<service
        android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.exservice"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" >
```

The only issue is AppStore would show which permission you use if below code shows in app's manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
```

In this example, you can access you resource by the same sign key, but definitely you can't broadcast package remove.

Comment: This does not solve the security problem, as any `android.*`permission that *you* could declare via `uses-permission` may also be declared and used by another app.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX can I do this in Android 12? 
install App A then install App B, and then call App B's component from App A;

in App A:

<permission android:name="com.mycoolcam.USE_CUSTOM1" android:protectionLevel="normal"/>

 ; and In App B:

<permission android:name="com.mycoolcam.USE_CUSTOM1"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

Comment: @ani0904071 No. This was a problem on very old versions of Android, but nowadays if you try to install an app that declares the same permissions as an existing app, the installation will fail.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX , yes I tired yesterday with android 12, it failed both in Android Studio and device :)